# nodequeue issue occured after updating whole site

Tags: nodes

After updating whole site and all modules to latest version of drupal. I got following errors. Due to this I'm not able to add content insite the nodequeue.

Notice: Undefined offset: 2 in nodequeue_handler_relationship_nodequeue->init() (line 19 of /home/dev/public_html/sites/all/modules/contrib/nodequeue/includes/views/nodequeue_handler_relationship_nodequeue.inc). Notice: Undefined offset: 2 in nodequeue_handler_relationship_nodequeue->init() (line 19 of /home/dev/public_html/sites/all/modules/contrib/nodequeue/includes/views/nodequeue_handler_relationship_nodequeue.inc

Comment: Are you really using nodequeue?

Comment: yes. It has so many features.